# javascript password meter not incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know this is frequently a question here, but i dont think it specifically relates to design pattern but instead more at my stupidity.

There is probably ridiculously simple solution to this, but i'm tired and it's starting to get to me a bit. i've fired it in the console and it responds accordingly but when i type anything into the input , it doesn't respond.

here's the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var passwordStrength = function (element){
    var password = element.val();
    var strength = [ 'Very Weak', 'Weak', 'Better', 'Strong', 'Very Strong' ];
    var score   = 0;
    // > 6
    if (password.length > 6){ 
        score+=1;
    }
    //has lower and uppercase     
    if ((password.match(/[a-z]/) ) && (password.match(/[A-Z]/))){
        score+=1;
    }
    //has number
    if (password.match(/\d+/)){
        score+=1;
    }
    //has special character
    if (password.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/)){
        score+=1;
    }
    //more than 12 characters
    if (password.length > 12){
        score+=1;
    }

    $('#pwdstrtxt').text(strength[score]);
    $('#pwdstrtxt').addClass('pwdText'+score);
    $('#pwdStrFill').addClass('pwdScore'+score);
}

passwordStrength($('#pass'));

});
```

here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGDLb/)

ideally i'd like the load bar and the text to change dynamically dependant on the input.

any help would be appreciated :) thanks.

Comment: I've never liked these password strength things. That thing reckons the password `Ab1!` is stronger than `sadasdkajfljdflakjsdlakdfladlakjsflaskfsdhglfjglkjeiruwpeivxmcnvqkuehfnvs`. I'd personally at least keep adding +1 for every six characters since passphrases (eg "Now is the winter of my discontent" are generally some of the best types (in terms of ease of memory and difficulty to crack just through length). Giving +1 for each extra six characters or similar might help make this more indicative. (Note: personal opinion for the most part)

Comment: a very nice insight, thank you. maybe i'll have another look at the pointing structure, perhaps giving a staggered amount of points depending on the length. but to recognise sentences with semantic meaning? i think that's a bit over my head lol.

Comment: @RuseellSims: Another good primer is http://xkcd.com/936/ which gives an attempt to estimate the entropy in short passwords with numbers and punctuation and longer passwords based on words and phrases. Recommended reading for anybody interested in password strength. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call the event each time the input is modified, like that:

```
$("#pass").on("keyup change", function() {
    passwordStrength($(this));
})
```

I've updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGDLb/13/)

Comment: if you removed the text or put weak password the text change but the bar not!

Comment: ah brilliant! i knew it would be something silly, i'll get my head round dom scripting one day. thank you :)

Comment: @ebramtharwat: that is an excellent point though due to a mistake in the original code and unrelated to the specific problem. For the benefit of OP it is because you aren't stripping the classes you've previously added so once you add the psdscore3 class you never remove it.

Comment: You could join the event declarations into one, just do `$("#pass").on("keyup change", foo);`. Also, `on()` is the prefered way to bind events since jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener on keyup.

```
$('#pass').on('keyup', function () {passwordStrength($(this))});
```

Also you need to update the password bar properly by using

```
$('#pwdStrFill').attr('class', 'pwdScore' + score);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGDLb/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this one its simple to use also...
[Jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-password-validation/)

Comment: it was more of a learning experience, to see how much of it i could do. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure that your code is executed when the user types something. This is done by binding to the keydown-event on the textfield.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pass').on('keydown change', function() { passwordStrength($('#pass'));});;
});
```

Then, you should also make sure that you remove the classes your set before adding the new ones to allow users to retype their password if they change their mind.

```
$('#pwdstrtxt').removeClass();
$('#pwdStrFill').removeClass();
```

I updated your fiddle to reflect these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/UGDLb/12/